# Simple table element in polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer

I've just started using polymer 1.0 and have searched around for a data table element to use in it. Lots of search results suggest using sortable-table ( http://files.stevenskelton.ca/sortable-table/examples/index.html ) hasn't quite yet been ported to polymer 1.0.

Is there any tutorial / resource on how one might build a simple (json fed) table in polymer?

It can't be difficult I imagine, I've just not wrapped my head around dom-repeat and things yet.

Thanks!

PS: my api produces data of this shape

```
[
{ key1:value1, key2:value2, keyn:valuen },
{ key1:value1, key2:value2, keyn:valuen },
{ key1:value1, key2:value2, keyn:valuen },
{ key1:value1, key2:value2, keyn:valuen }
]
```

```

Answer (score 2):

At the time of this answer, [here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-elements) we can see that developers have "elements planned" including paper-data-table. I'm waiting for this element. Even I think for the time in which this element ends to make, you could easily migrate the sortable-table to Polymer 1.0 XD

Answer (score 1):

I think [iron-list](http://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list) would be a good candidate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is I kind of need to do this today, not some time in the wonderful future :)

Comment: Take a look at vaadin-grid. It has unfortunately a rather complicated dependency/build process but should play well with polymer

Comment: I agree, it is really overkill for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you. I wish there was a good grid component.

Comment: If you look at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/ui/file_manager/file_manager/foreground/js/ui/ you can see the nice implementation for the ChromeOS file manager